# Какую библиотеку необходимо установить чтобы исправить ошибку ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'loglevels'?

Tags: python

При запуске скрипта на python выдается сообщение об ошибке `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'loglevels'`
Подскажите пожалуйста какую библиотеку необходимо установить?
Команда `pip install loglevels` (с вариациями) ничего не дала.
Перерыл Инет, но к сожалению пока ничего не нашел.

Comment: добавь твой код

Comment: не уловил о чем речь.
добавить код, который выдает сообщение об ошибке?
эта ошибка возникает при запуске `odoo-bin` (OpenERP)
могу привести полный стек текста ошибки

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace('odoo.addons')

  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2147, in declare_namespace
    declare_namespace(parent)
  
File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2163, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item) `

Comment: ` File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2098, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 399, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 823, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 682, in load_module
 `

Comment: ` File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 248, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 608, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\novikov.sergey\Source\Repos\odoo\odoo\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    import loglevels
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'loglevels' `